# How to setup supabase for developing with team?

Tags: supabase

I am working on a project. I am using supabase. What if I want to make my repo open source and allow other people to contribute to it. I have custom functions, triggers, databases, Email SMTP, and lot other services. How can other developers in the team can have the same settings for local development?

Do I have to use docker are there any other ways? If I can setup all these stuffs in docker, then please provide me a guide which I can follow.

Comment: Supabase recommends running database migrations using the Supabase CLI. It allows others to copy the same environment you have in your project locally. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/local-development